# Moving most recent changes from trunk to new branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch

I checked in commit 100 last night on our trunk. Another developer checked in commit 101 this afternoon on the trunk. I wished for him to create a branch instead. What is the easiest way to revert the trunk back to 100 and to create a new branch that contains 101?

Answer (score 1):

Create the branch now from 101. Once the new branch exists use the rollback command to undo 101 in trunk.

If you are using TFS 2012 you just need to view history of trunk and then highlight checkin 101 and select rollback complete changeset. Checkin the rollback, this will be checkin 102.

You may have problems when you come to merge the new branch back to trunk, if TFS thinks the rollback takes precedence (because its more recent) then use a visual studio command line to do the merge and use `tf merge $/teamproject/devbranch $/teamproject/trunk /recursive /force`